# Limit the number of records searched in XMLRPC OODO

Tags: android, xml-rpc, openerp-7

I am an android developer who is now working with OODO API.

My aim is to read a specific amount of data present in the res.partner object in the OpenERP.

I used the **below code** to get all the data's present in the **res.partner** object.

```
   String[] arrayOfString4 = new String[4];
            arrayOfString4[0] = "name";
            arrayOfString4[1] = "date";
            arrayOfString4[2] = "state_id";
            arrayOfString4[3] = "ho_branch_id";
            arrayOfString4[4] = "client_id";

tableId = (Object[]) client1.call("execute", DB_NAME, UID, PASSWORD,  "res.partner", "search", new Object[0]);   

Object[] tableitems = (Object[]) client1.call("execute", DB_NAME, UID, PASSWORD, "res.partner", "read", tableId, arrayOfString4);
```

This code retrieves more than 20,000 data's where **I only need the first 50 data's.**

I checked this [OODO API link](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/api_integration.html) for a solution.And from there I tried this.

```
tableId = (Object[]) client1.call("execute", DB_NAME, UID, PASSWORD,  "res.partner", "search", new Object[0],new HashMap() {{ put("limit",50); }});

Object[] tableitems = (Object[]) client1.call("execute", DB_NAME, UID, PASSWORD, "res.partner", "read", tableId, arrayOfString4);
```

But I get an error

```
 java.lang.string cannot be converted into java.lang.integer
```

Can anyone please help me how to limit the number of data's read???
I hope my question is clear enough..I am new at this.

Thank you.